# SuperSpeed USB Port causes power surge on external Harddrive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, usb-3

I was testing my [new laptop hub](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08B1M79ZV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) and attempted to plug in [my extern hard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VP5X239) drive to on of the SuperSpeed USB-A Ports. Explorer openend normally and I was able to browse files until I opened a certain folder and the drive started making a clicking noise and proceeded to lock up my computer until I unplugged it after ca. 30secs. After that, the harddrive wasn't functional with any computer I plugged it into, meaning it didn't even appear in explorer and would make the clicking sound a few seconds before powering down.

When I tried reinstalling the driver in device manager by uninstalling and re-plugging, I get a faulty driver icon in device manager and a "this device could not be recognized" by windows.

Before this usage, the harddrive was perfectly functional. All other devices have functioned normally with the same port (Bluetooth mouse and keyboard, webcam, usb-stick, usb-c data-transfer cable). Do you have an idea what could be the issue? Could the harddrive have been damaged by being plugged into the port? What is the best recommendation for how to proceed if I want to keep my data? Is that even possible? Does it make sense to try to remove the casing and see how it functions from the inside?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "Do you have an idea what could be the issue?" - HDD encountered a mechanical failure.  The "clicking" sound likely was the head assembly.  " Could the hard drive have been damaged by being plugged into the port?" - Unlikely

Comment: ... it just happened to be at the brink of self destruction at that moment in time. (yes really). Say that there was some kind of particle in there that moved about, and hit the read head (with the help of the rotating disk) at that instant.

Comment: @Ramhound why is that?

Comment: @ Hannu. What do you mean? Can you rephrase what you said? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @DelectableTea - Why is what? Why did your HDD fail? It's a mechanical drive, they fail, clicking is a strong indication of that fact. **Your HDD has failed**

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but there's simply no evidence to support a power surge _(this theory is only in the title and has no supporting evidence that a power surge even occurred)_. I'm not even sure if it's possible for a USB hub to power surge to downstream devices, and it wouldn't just be on only one device that was connected _(even then, it would fry the external HDD's power supply, not the drive)_. USB hubs, unless states otherwise, provide a maximum 5V/1A output - some may do 5V/2A, but none usually go beyond that unless it supports QC charging.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ It's simply not possible for a USB hub to pass more voltage/current than it was designed to pass to the output connectors due to the PCB components that have been electrically engineered in such a way to prevent this very thing - USB ports cannot output more voltage/current than they were engineered to pass. As to the clicking, this is a normal sound all mechanical HDDs make, occurring when the heads reach the end of the platter and are reset to center by the voicecoil. The only way to determine if it's the case or the drive is to remove the drive from the case and test.

Comment: @DelectableTea How long was the USB3 cable that was used? Has a different, known good USB 3 cable been tried? If so, **and** drive is not detected by `DiskPart` _(`WinKey`+`R`→Open: `DiskPart`→ OK)_ → `lis dis`, to determine whether it's the casing's power supply or the drive itself you'll need to remove the drive from the casing and use a different USB to SATA connector _(if it's a 3.5" drive, it'll require a powered external drive housing for 3.5" drives since those require 12V)_ to determine if it's detected and I'd run a long S.M.A.R.T test, reviewing the data via `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to "fix" a dead disk, because most likely
you won't succeed. This is a hardware error that you cannot fix with
software or drivers.

It's possible that the hub is broken and is dangerous. I DON'T
suggest to do the logical test and connect another USB, since it
might kill this one as well.

I would suggest to junk or replace the new hub.
I wouldn't take the chance of losing more USB devices.

Comment: as  I said, I already plugged in many other usb devices and they all are fine.

Comment: In this case, the disk was already failing and the additional power available in SuperSpeed ports was just too much for it and hastened its death.

Comment: @harrymc - Debatable that a external HDD failed due to the power provided by SuperSeed since the drive was designed to work over a SuperSeed USB port. The HDD likely was failing, and the simple act of using the HDD, caused the failure.

Comment: @Ramhound: A faulty disk may not behave as it was designed to do. All we have are theories, and yours is as valid as mine.

Comment: @harrymc The issue with both theories is there's no evidence to support either. USB voltage and current is tightly controlled by the electrical engineering of the PCB and it's components, and hubs only output 5V/1A, possibly 5V/2A, unless otherwise stated _(such as a hub supporting QC charging)_. An electrical receptacle, be it a USB port or one in a wall, only outputs the voltage and current requested by the device plugged into it. The theory of a power surge is only mentioned in the OP's title, with no supporting evidence anywhere in the question's body.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ If a power surge did occur, there would be physical evidence of it in the form of off-gassing capacitors _(at a minimum)_, the hub's port would likely no longer function, multiple devices would be affected, the external USB HDD"s power supply wouldn't function to power the drive, etc. - it wouldn't just be on only one device that was connected _(even then, it would fry the external HDD's power supply's PCB components, not the drive's PCB)_. As to the clicking, it's a normal sound all mechanical HDDs make when the heads reach the end of the platter and are reset by the voicecoil